# QDockWidget sized wrong when docked on right side of Main Window

Tags: qt, qdockwidget

I am new to Qt and I am trying to create a DockWidget that docks on the right of the window. I set a maximum and minimum width for the dock (as you will see in the code below). This works if the dock widget is added with `Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea`, but when it is added with `Qt::RightDockWidgetArea`, The dock is "padded" out to the center of the window, like this:
[image: The red area shows the dock widget boundary.]

I am probably not sizing the dock in the correct way.. Here is the code for this window:

```
int main(int argv, char** args)
{
    QApplication app(argv, args);
    QMainWindow window;
    QDesktopWidget* desktop = QApplication::desktop();
    //Docks
    QDockWidget* propertyDock = new QDockWidget("",&window);
    QWidget* propertyDockContents = new QWidget;

    //This sets the window in the center of the screen.
    int wWidth = 800; int wHeight = 600;
    window.setGeometry(QRect( (desktop->width()-wWidth)/2 , (desktop->height()-wHeight)/2 ,wWidth,wHeight));

    propertyDock->setAllowedAreas(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
    propertyDockContents->setMaximumWidth(200);
    propertyDockContents->setMinimumWidth(20);

    propertyDock->setWidget(propertyDockContents);
    window.addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea,propertyDock);

    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Is there a "correct" way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the documentation:

> Note: Creating a main window without a central widget is not supported. You must have a central widget even if it is just a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can't creating a main window without a central widget, But you can set central widget's height to zero.
[MainWindow.cpp](https://github.com/blab-liuliang/echo/blob/master/editor/echo/Base/UI/MainWindow/MainWindow.cpp)

```
centralWidget()->setMaximumHeight(0);
```