# How to set QDockWidget initial (default) size in the app with no central widget (PyQt4)?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qdockwidget

I have an app with a lot of [QDockWidgets](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qdockwidget.html) and without central widget. I want to set some of those [QDockWidgets](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qdockwidget.html) initial size (size at application's start), but I don't want to limit their min/max sizes.

How to do it? For example, I need to set initial size 150x75 to one of them. I tried obvious methods (such as [QWidget.Resize()](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#resize-2) relating to dock widget content), but it didn't work at all.

Here is a simplified model of situation:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([''])

mw = QtGui.QMainWindow() # mw = MainWindow
mw.setCentralWidget(None)
mw.showMaximized()

mw.dockWdg1 = QtGui.QDockWidget(mw)
mw.content1 = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
mw.dockWdg1.setWidget(mw.content1)
mw.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea(2), mw.dockWdg1)
mw.dockWdg1.setWindowTitle("1st dock widget")

mw.dockWdg2 = QtGui.QDockWidget(mw)
mw.content2 = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
mw.dockWdg2.setWidget(mw.content2)
mw.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea(1), mw.dockWdg2)
mw.dockWdg2.setWindowTitle("2nd dock widget")

mw.dockWdg3 = QtGui.QDockWidget(mw)
mw.content3 = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
mw.dockWdg3.setWidget(mw.content3)
mw.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.DockWidgetArea(1), mw.dockWdg3)
mw.dockWdg3.setWindowTitle("3rd dock widget")

mw.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: `QMainWindow` must always have a central widget but you can try to set its size to 0.

Comment: @alexisdm, well, how to do that? Can you please post some code that can help me? Thank you!

Comment: For example, with `mw.setCentralQWidget(QWidget())` and `mw.centralWidget().setFixedSize(0,0)`. [That question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10067821/894321) shows the kind of problems you can have without setting the central widget.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The dockwidgets will be incorporated into the layout of the main window, so any attempt to resize them will be ignored.

The standard workaround for this is to create a subclass of the content widget and reimplement its `sizeHint`:

```
class TreeWidget(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(150, 75)

mw.dockWdg2 = QtGui.QDockWidget(mw)
mw.content2 = TreeWidget()
mw.dockWdg2.setWidget(mw.content2)
```

However, this will only work to the extent that you also carefully manage the sizes of the other dockwidgets. And of course maximiizing the main window is also going to have a impact on the final outcome.

You might also want to consider using [QMainWindow.saveState](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#saveState) and [QMainWindow.restoreState](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#restoreState) to manage the initial state of your dockwidgets.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fixedSize function, as setFixedWidth/setFixedHeight.

Comment: This constains the widget to exactly that size; the original poster wanted just the default size, not the minimum and maximum size to be set.

Answer (score 0):

I think reimplementing the `sizeHint()` function based on MainWindow's size is better than just returning a fixed size.

[Source Code](https://github.com/blab-liuliang/echo/blob/master/editor/echo/Base/UI/RenderWindow/RenderWindow.cpp)

```
// size hint
QSize RenderWindow::sizeHint() const
{
    float width = MainWindow::instance()->width() * 0.3f;
    float height = MainWindow::instance()->height() * 0.65f;
    return QSize( width, height);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Anyone landing on this old question since Qt 5.6 should look at `QMainWindow::resizeDocks()`

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#resizeDocks

eg:

```py
mw.resizeDocks({ mw.dockWdg1,  mw.dockWdg1 }, { 260, 540 }, Qt.Vertical);
```

(Not sure that's 100% valid Py, but you get the idea...)